# Ember data: Is there a way to change the store of a record?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on a mobile project using Emberjs.

I've created a custom store for a data-set that's large enough that ember-data stores can't handle directly without a long load time.

What this custom store does is create a few Ember Data Stores and mange them trough a hash.

At one point I need to move a record from one store to another because of changes in the parameters that make-up the hash.

I tried doing serialization + re-instanciation by `Store.createRecord(Model, oldRecord.toJSON())` but I lose the reference to the record and other parts of the system are dependent on that.

I then get rid of the old record: `oldRecord.get('stateManager').goToState('deleted.saved')`;

If it weren't for this reference issue I could get away with this `newRecord.get('stateManager').goToState('updated')` to get the the record into a dirty state (in which I need it to be).

I also tried the crazy `record.set('store', newStore)`

I am willing to delve deep into the internals of DS.Store; found these good links with details of the store's internals but I don't know what's the best way to do this.

http://nragaz.com/post/41076138457/is-ember-data-just-unfinished-or-fundamentally-broken
http://www.kaspertidemann.com/where-are-the-records-stored-in-ember-data/

Is there a easy way to switch the store of a record without loosing it's reference?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why multiple stores. Do you need all the data loaded first ?

Comment: @ken I need multiple stores for performance reasons since it is mobile and I have limited resources. This gives me more control. By using my custom store I managed to go from 10s to .5s.

Comment: Would pagination, or on demand loading works for you instead ? Again do you need all the data at startup time ?